# Load testing with getting URL parameter and CSRF token in the body

Tags: testing, jmeter, load, performance-testing

Please help with solving Sign up load test with using URL parameter and CSRF token in the response body

My case:

- I have sing up page and enter data(like user name, email, pass etc) [www.example.com/reg](http://www.example.com/reg)
- I click on Sing up and the system adds to sing up page [www.example.com/reg](http://www.example.com/reg) parameter test. (it looks like [www.example.com/reg?test=some_value](http://www.example.com/reg?test=some_value))
- I received response in JSON format where we have my data and random CSRF token
  Example of JSON
  {"pass":"value","mail_name":{"e-mail":"value","name":{"first":"value"}},"csrf_token":"some_value"}

My question is:
I need to perform the following test.

1. Enter all data(it can be done by CSD Data Set config) in Sign up page
2. Obtain test paramater(it is each time different) that added to URL only after clicking on Sign up button in Sing up page
3. Inject CSRF token to response because it is each time different.

In general I should each load test obtain test parameter from URL and obtain CSRF token and pass it to response.

If you will be able to help with examples. Much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

2. If the parameter is being added as a part of the [Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) - it can be extracted using [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) from URL or from Location response header.

   [image]
3. CSRF token can be extracted from the response using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be as simple as just `csrf_token`

   [image]